# How do I notify a user if a pen drive is connected in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a interactive script to copy files from a pen drive to hard drive and vice versa. (I already have written the script to take care of this). I am stuck at this part, as to How do I notify a user if a pen drive is connected/disconnected in a bash script? 
After detection of the usb drive I would like to leave it to the user to actually run the script further or not.
I tried "udevadm monitor" which throws up device specific events. Seems like I need to find a way to build on it.

Comment: Please take the time to read the help topics in how to ask. Note however that this is not a write your code service. You need to do your research, and show what you have got so far, and give a specific problem

Comment: Maybe you could leverage `lsusb` somehow, to check available usb devices.

Comment: Or save and compare the output of `mount` for the addition of the new filesystem.

Comment: @mjs please take the time and read the [tour] yourself. **Not** all questions on StackOverflow are about **show the code**, see the example question in the [tour]. (about the swift based apps). The OP not asking for a code, but for a programming help - how to do something - what is covered by the _a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_ - defined in the [help/on-topic]. Also he shows his research effort (`udevadm`). This question has bad formatting, but otherwise is perfectly valid.

Comment: @jm666 I "I tried udevadm" does not actually explain where the OP has got to, and where exactly they are stuck. I actually wish there was more quality content that isn't "what's wrong with this code", and deal with more abstract "what is the best approach to do x" I agree that this is actually a valid question, and potentially has the makings of a good one. It just isn't yet.

Comment: @jm666 which is why I haven't flag for closure

Comment: @mjs - OK, i'm not an "diamond" moderator - just an oridinary user - as you. I'm only disappointed a bit with increasing number of close votes and comments like "show code" - without reading the whole question. Of course, (maybe) this question will be closed - for example because someone will flag it as an duplicate. (here is a big probability, than someone already asked this) :) So, don't get my words very personally :) :)

Comment: And to be fair, I was perhaps overly critical. I didn't spot the statement about udevadm, I had switched off before.